# Ruby Mechanize + Tor?

Tags: ruby, http, web, automation, tor

Trying to build a program that automates interactions with web pages through TOR. I need to be able to store and delete cookies, and change TOR identities. Is this something that is possible with Mechanize? Is there a library made to work with TOR?

Answer (score 0):

You can totally abstract away from this by simply passing all of your traffic through TOR.  One example is setting up a tor-only wifi access point.  If you want to be private, simply switch your computer over to it and you are covered.  Here is the project: https://code.google.com/p/torberry/

Comment: Right, but one of the requirements is being able to change identities on the fly using code... So, is there a Ruby-Tor client?